# Using spring data jpa to save results in field loss

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

## Desc

I have a SpringBoot  application using spring data jpa.

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.11'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
mysql version: 8.0
```

My idea is very simple, I have some tables with the same structure (except for the different table names). More tables may be added in the future (I don't want to repeat the coding), so I want to insert directly according to the class name Its corresponding table. But I tested and found that when I used `repository.save()`, jpa only inserted the id for me, and the other two fields I set were not written. This confuses me. Below is my code.

## Code

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.dto.BaseClass;
import com.example.demo.dto.Other;
import com.example.demo.dto.User;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationContextAware {
    static Map<String, Class<? extends BaseClass>> CLAZZ_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        CLAZZ_MAP.put("user", User.class);
        CLAZZ_MAP.put("other", Other.class);
    }

    ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            Map<String, CrudRepository> repositoryMap = context.getBeansOfType(CrudRepository.class);
            repositoryMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
                Class<? extends BaseClass> clazz = CLAZZ_MAP.get(k.substring(0, k.indexOf("Repository")));
                try {
                    BaseClass baseClass = clazz.newInstance();
                    baseClass.setOther("a");
                    baseClass.setPhone("b");
                    v.save(baseClass);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;

public class BaseClass {
    @Column
    String phone;
    @Column
    String other;

    // ignore getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "other")
public class Other extends BaseClass{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    // ignore getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseClass{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    // ignore getter and setter 
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface BaseRepository {
}

public interface OtherRepository extends CrudRepository<Other, Integer>, BaseRepository{

}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>, BaseRepository {

}
```

## DB query result

```
> select * from user;
id phone other
1  ,    , 

> select * from other;
id phone other
1  ,    ,
```

So what should I do to get back those fields I was missing.
I overwrote the phone and other fields in the subclasses (user and other), and then used save, and they all saved successfully. This confuses me even more.

Comment: I debugged the source code and found that jpa did not scan the fields of the parent class when getting the fields.  caused this problem. I'm not sure if it's correct. I may raise an issue later

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the superclass with `@MappedSuperclass`.

For more details take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance